# Unable to install mysql-connector-python

Tags: python-3.x

I can't install mysql connector with below error, please help advise needed action to proceed installation of module..See below command/errors:

C:\Users\a0229010>python -m pip install mysql-connector-python==3.7.3
Collecting mysql-connector-python==3.7.3
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000017975C3B5C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/mysql-connector-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000017975C3BB38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/mysql-connector-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000017975C3B7B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/mysql-connector-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000017975C3B438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/mysql-connector-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000017975C3BF60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/mysql-connector-python/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python==3.7.3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python==3.7.3

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change your *Python Package Index*

Or you can use follow code to have a try:

`pip --default-timeout=100 install <package> -i <indexURL> --trusted-host <domain>`

e.g  when i install *pandas*

`pip --default-timeout=100 install pandas -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple --trusted-host pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn`

Answer (score 0):

It says it in the last line

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python==3.7.3

You are fixing the version to 3.7.3
However, according to PyPi, there is no version 3.7.3 available.
See here
https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/#history

Latest version is 8.0.31